# Java version of app does not match the Java version in exception stack trace

Tags: java

I'm starting my app from a specific folder that has Java v1.7_40 through this command:

```
start /D <path_to_java1.7_40_bin> /HIGH /B javaw.exe .....
```

My system Java is v1.8_60 i.e. my `PATH` environment variable is pointing to Java v1.8_60.

When there is an exception occurring in my app, I see:

```
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_60]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.27]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_60]
```

I'm positive my app is starting without any errors. Can anyone tell me why the version of Java in the stack trace does not match the version the app is starting from?

Comment: If you want to use a specific version of javaw, then I'd use the full path to it, rather than using /D here. Otherwise, it's difficult to say whether the path variable will be ignored or not. And I'd perhaps output the value of <path_to_java1.7_40_bin> to ensure that you're starting in the right directory, if it's a variable. The trouble is that the /D only tells your application what its starting directory is, for reference internally. However, if you're calling this start command from another directory, then it's still going to use your path variable to locate javaw.exe.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was it. I mentioned the full path to javaw and it fixed it.

Comment: Posted that as an answer for this one. Glad that sorted it for you :)

Comment: How did you get the version number in your stack traces? That seems really useful, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Comment: We use Log4j from Apache and I think it displays the java version by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a specific version of javaw, then I'd use the full path to it, rather than using /D here. Otherwise, it's difficult to say whether the path variable will be ignored or not. So...

```
start /HIGH /B <path_to_java1.7_40_bin>\javaw.exe
```

And I'd perhaps output the value of  to ensure that you're starting in the right directory, if it's a variable. The trouble is that the /D only tells your application what its starting directory is, for reference internally. However, if you're calling this start command from another directory, then it's still going to use your path variable to locate javaw.exe.